# Install a certificate for a local cluster

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I have some code to authenticate with Azure Key Vault in order to retrieve some secrets. I am authentication using a client id and certificate instead of a client id and secret. This code works great in a normal console app:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
try
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

    var matchingCertificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
    if (matchingCertificates.Count != 1)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return matchingCertificates[0];
}
finally
{
    if (store != null) store.Close();
}
```

As soon as I try using this code in a stateful service application it is no longer able to find the certificate.

How can I install a certificate so that it is available to my local cluster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Service Fabric applications run under the NETWORK SERVICE account, so you'll need to make sure that account has access/permissions to the certificate.

EDIT:

For a cluster running on your local box you do that by finding the certificate either using certmgr.msc or the relevant mmc snap-in and then right click > All Tasks > Manage Private Keys and then giving read permissions to NETWORK SERVICE.

For remote clusters in Azure, you can do that using a [custom script extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript/) on the VMs of the scale set that will run a PowerShell script that sets up the permissions you want. For example, it could do something like the following:

```
$certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $certificateThumbprint}

# Get file path
$certificateFilePath = "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\" + $cert.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName

# Take ownership of the file so that permissions can be set
takeown /F $certificateFilePath

# Give the NETWORK SERVICE read permissions
$acl = (Get-Item $certificateFilePath).GetAccessControl('Access')
$rule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule "NETWORK SERVICE","Read","Allow"
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path $certificateFilePath -AclObject $acl
```

Comment: So it will still see all certificates that are installed on my local machine, as long as it has access to them?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Rather than giving access manually, you can have Service Fabric automatically give access to specific certs by defining users, groups, and access policies in ApplicationManifest.xml. See this doc for more info on setting this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-runas-security/#a-complete-application-manifest-example

Comment: Can you provide more details around how you grant access to the certificate in Service Fabric? That document talks about SSL endpoint certificates but that is not my use case. I am using a certificate private key to authenticate with a KeyVault resource.

Comment: I've done that using a Custom Script Extension on the VM definition of the scale set that will run a script to set those permissions. However, @VaclavTurecek might be able to provide a more elegant solution using the RunAs stuff.

Comment: Note that in Germany "NETWORK SERVICE" is "Netzwerkdienst" - even if you switch the Windows language to English. That is why it is better to use `New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-20")` etc.

Answer (score 9):

The reason this doesn't work as-is is because Service Fabric runs under the NETWORK SERVICE account, which, without configuration, does not have access to the certificate.

For us at least, this scenario caused a "Keyset does not exist" exception when using the `KeyVaultClient` provided by Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault to connect to Key Vault using the certificate.

A solution to this is to include the certificate in your `ApplicationManifest.xml`, which instructs Service Fabric to give the NETWORK SERVICE account access to the certificate;

```
<ApplicationManifest>
   <!-- snip -->
   <Principals>
      <Users>
         <User Name="NetworkServiceAccount" AccountType="NetworkService" />
      </Users>
   </Principals>
   <Policies>
      <SecurityAccessPolicies>
         <SecurityAccessPolicy ResourceRef="KeyVaultCert" PrincipalRef="NetworkServiceAccount" GrantRights="Full" ResourceType="Certificate" />
      </SecurityAccessPolicies>
   </Policies>
   <Certificates>
      <SecretsCertificate X509FindValue="1ABCD86B815F37123459A34C1BA9EDEBABCEDF1" Name="KeyVaultCert" />
   </Certificates>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

... where both `NetworkServiceAccount` and `KeyVaultCert` are arbitrary names used by the `<SecurityAccessPolicy />` element to reference the user and certificate.

See also https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-runas-security/#a-complete-application-manifest-example

Comment: This is the better answer, cleaner and easier. Works flawless!

Comment: It seems that a certificate rollover is unsupported with this solution. Azure Service Fabric does not unregister the port with something like "netsh http ssl remove .." and upgrading an application with a new thumbprint fails...

Comment: One clarification which bit me: Make sure to install your certificate into the LOCALMACHINE (not CurrentUser) location. If you just dbl-clicked on the *.pfx/cer file, then it goes to CurrentUser. Which will give you the FABRIC_E_CERTIFICATE_NOTFOUND error during codepackage deployment step.

Comment: @SatThiru If you add the certificate via the VM Scale Set resource (see [here](https://ronaldwildenberg.com/custom-domain-name-and-certificate-for-your-azure-service-fabric-cluster/) for info), the certificate is automatically installed in the LocalMachine store.